# Edit character in Dragon Age Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I had a weird graphic bug when I created my character, and now he has ridiculous red hair. I know there is a console in this game. Is there a command to launch face editor again? Most games have that.

Comment: I'm assuming this is on PC?

Comment: Yes, sir, you assume right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get to the Black Emporium (revealed on the world map) there is a Transformation Mirror there that lets you edit your character.  I got there around level 4 or 5...pretty early in the game.  It gives you unlimited character editing at no cost.

Answer (score 1):

**No, you can't** edit your character and yes people don't like it. Probably this feature will be added later in DLC, [like in the first Skyrim DLC Dawnguard](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Galathil).

Sources: Bioware forums threads ([first](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/519305-wait-did-bioware-screw-up-again-you-cannot-edit-your-inquisitor-afterwards/page-3) and [second](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/528044-that-ability-to-customise-your-characters-appearance-in-game-is-desperately-needed/)) plus [bonus reddit thread](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/528044-that-ability-to-customise-your-characters-appearance-in-game-is-desperately-needed/) about most needed thing - which is ingame character customisation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. Although in Skyrim you could do it with ingame console no problem, unless you were playing on a console. Consoles don't get consoles, I guess.